# Remove all '+' from array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this, and I want to remove the `+` sign from the below array:

```
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015', '+(91)-80-411311456', '+(91)-80-411311016'];
```

I have tried the following but it is not working:

```
var toRemove = "+";
arr = arr.filter(function(el){
    return !toRemove.includes(el);
});
```

How do I remove all `+` signs from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method. Where [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can be use for replacing `+` symbol from the string.

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015', '+(91)-80-411311456', '+(91)-80-411311016'];

var toRemove = '+'; // use regex `/\+/g` for removing all occurrence

arr = arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.replace(toRemove, '');
});

console.log(arr);
```

---

Or simple for loop is enough.

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015', '+(91)-80-411311456', '+(91)-80-411311016'];

var toRemove = '+'; // use regex `/\+/g` for removing all occurrence

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace(toRemove, '');
}

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 4):

`Array#map` would do it. No jQuery required

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015','+(91)-80-411311456','+(91)-80-411311016'];
arr = arr.map(o => o.replace('+',''));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove every +,

```
arr = arr.map((str) => str.split('+').join(''))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter` as its name suggests, is used for filtering array based on a condition. This will return a subset of original but will not change the data in it.

What you are looking for is `array.map` and there are few good answers on it already. So, I'll add some other variations that you can use.

#### for

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015','+(91)-80-411311456','+(91)-80-411311016'];

for(var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i] = arr[i].replace('+', '');
}

console.log(arr)
```

#### forEach

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015','+(91)-80-411311456','+(91)-80-411311016'];

arr.forEach((x,i)=>{arr[i] = arr[i].replace('+', '')})

console.log(arr)
```

#### map

```js
var arr = ['+(91)-80-411311015','+(91)-80-411311456','+(91)-80-411311016'];

arr = arr.map(x=>x.replace('+',''));

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = arr.map( function(o) { return o.replace('+','');});
```

Comment: Hey, this is a partial answer. Please add some explanation as to What have you changed and Why. Also, this has been answer already, so Please do not repeat answers,